# OpenAPI Generator generates generic Parameter names

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, gradle-plugin, openapi-generator

I'm currently experiencing a struggle with the OpenAPI Generator Plugin in Gradle.
When I generate a new API Interface with the following settings in my build.gradle:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/api.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir".toString()
    apiPackage = "<package name>"
    configOptions = [
            interfaceOnly     : "true",
            library           : "spring-cloud",
            skipDefaultInterface: "true",
            modelPackage      : "<package name>",
            apiPackage: "<package name>",
            serializableModel: "true",
            useOptional: "true",
    ]
}
```

The output API Interface uses generic Parameter names. For example var1, var2 and so on.
Example:

```java
ResponseEntity<Void> deleteOrganisationById(@ApiParam(value = "Mandant",required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "MANDANT",required = true) BigDecimal var1, @ApiParam(value = "ID of the organisation to be deleted",required = true) @PathVariable("id") String var2);
```

**How can I change this so it uses some kind of talking names for the parameters? E.g. mandant for the MANDANT parameter etc.?**

Comment: With the maven plugin 5.3.0 my generated classes are using the correct names that are specified in the yml file. Are you using the `name`tag in the yml?

Comment: Yes I am using the name tag. Example:
`
parameters:
        - name: X-Mandant
          in: header
          description: Mandant
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
`
Also tried it by adding it to the components/parameters and using it with `$ref` but also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `ensureUniqueParams` option to `true` in the plugins configOptions.

Example `pom.xml`:

```
<configOptions>
    <ensureUniqueParams>true</ensureUniqueParams>
    ... other Parameters
</configOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using?

Using openapi.generator `5.3.0` with gradle `7.2` the var names match the spec file

```
id "org.openapi.generator" version "5.3.0"
```

And the api model.yaml

```yaml
  parameters:
    - name: mandant
    required: true
```

Comment: I use plugin version 5.3.0 with Gradle 7.3.3 and it doesn't work.

Comment: Anyone able to fix it ?